Orchestration in AWS Glue

Hi All,
I have a workflow in AWS Glue that triggers the same Job (JobA) with
different parameters, for example, JobA - Param1, JobA - Param2,
etc..
I now have a requirement where I need to trigger another job (JobB)
after the successful completion of all the previous running jobs
(JobA).
My problem is that since its the same job that's being triggered
concurrently but just with different parameters, Glue recognizes the
first job to reach the succeeded status and triggers the next job.
Example of what happens:
JobA - Param1 -> Completed   JobA - Param2 - > Running   JobB -> Triggered.
This is what I would like to achieve in Glue.
Example of what I want to achieve:
JobA - Param1 -> Completed   JobA - Param2 - > Completed   JobB -> Triggered
Any guidance/help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

